# CALayer changes not shown up when written inside initWithCoder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, calayer

I'm trying to do some CALayer stuff on a UIButton that resides inside a uitableviewcell.
I've imported  but the CALayer manipulation is not working.
When I moved it to cellForRowAtIndexPath method it works fine.
I do want to make the change once inside the class of the cell itself and not inside the table creation table.
Do you have any ideas ?

By the way, I do see the NSLog text on the init (so I know it entered the block).

Thanks !

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"STARTED coder init in testResultCell");
        [[self.bubbleMore layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [[self.bubbleMore layer] setBorderWidth:3.0f];
        [[self.bubbleMore layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
        [[self.bubbleMore layer] setCornerRadius:20.0f];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: is the layer already available inside initWithCoder? I think you have to do the manipulation when presented to screen...

Comment: You stated "I do want to make the change once inside the class of the cell itself" but then you accepted an answer that required putting the code in the view controller rather than the answer that met your requirement.

Comment: You are right Timothy, sorry (changed it).
I'm still new to this and I've voted for the other response after I've edited it a bit (didn't think about the fact that the change might not take place).
Tnx for the tip and answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code to `awakeWithNib`. Your outlets won't be connected yet in `initWithCoder`. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib):

> When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet instance variables set.

Answer (score 1):

User interface objects are not available until `viewDidLoad` is called, which actually loads  controls from your `xib` or `Storyboard`. Please move your code to `viewDidLoad` and it should work just fine.

If you add a breakpoint and look at the `self.bubbleMore`, it is going to be `nil` in `initWithCode` function.